# How to tell a person that they can come/go through a door before you...

Tags: phrase-usage, idioms, slang, formal-language, informal-language

One thing that comes to my mind is "Please, come in" or just "Please" (this is what I use mostly). *Come in* suggests me that you are standing in a room, but what if you are in a corridor?

What do you say in these cases? Formal or informal. Would be great if you could bring a few examples of what you say to your friends jokingly, like is it possible to say something like "fly in" or something along these lines? :)
Thank you.

Comment: "go on in" if you're in the corridor with the person. "come on in" if you're inside the room.

Comment: ...or are you asking for them to move out of the way so you can go past?  (More or less what _"Give way"_ means.)

Comment: The title is confusing, and it's not grammatical.

Comment: @pazzo, How to rename it then? You want to say a person that they can go/come on in first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're just standing about by the door, blocking someone else from going through, obviously you should apologise while moving out of the way, so ***Pardon me*** or ***Excuse me*** would seem reasonable. Unless you want to make a *virtue* of being there, saying ***Allow me*** [to open the door] as you open it.

If you *also* intend to go through the door, ***After you*** as you step aside. Depending on the situation you might say ***Ladies first*** or ***Age before beauty***, but these are often somewhat facetious usages today.

Comment: +1 for "After you." As for "age before beauty," that one mostly works when the person you are deferring to is older than you.

Comment: @J.R. I'd be hesitant to use 'age before beauty' with anyone other than a good friend, or a colleague of very similar age - certainly not with someone who is clearly older… nor the boss ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin - Great point. I've only heard this used among jovial friends, and usually the person making the remark is only a few years younger . The remark is intended to be a good-natured jab at that person's age, as if it were more like a decade or more, when in fact it's more likely just a year or two.

Comment: @Tetsujin, J.R.:  I can certainly imagine *me* saying ***Ladies first*** (semi-facetiously, with a smile) as I defer to a woman of any age re access to a door, seat, serving counter, etc. And I'm sure are at least some people in some circumstances would use it *sincerely*. I agree the ***Age before beauty*** one must always be at least partly jocular/light-hearted (although it's a bit of a cliche, it was always intended to be *witty*, not *formal, polite*). But a younger woman might still say it to an older one (future mother-in-law, during first meeting?) with at least *some* sincerity.

Answer (score 1):

If you simply mean to say that the person should go inside, while you're standing outside, you can use:

> Go on in

These are similar expressions, but these mean that someone should move further in the direction he/she was going, not necessarily enter a specific place:

> Go ahead
>
> Continue

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go in after them I would say "after you", otherwise I would say "this way(, please)". In either case, I would move my hand and point into the doors.